# Is it possible to use Disqus without using links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, comments, disqus

So I need a comment system for my site but when I was reading the tutorial on how to install it, it seems that the comments are linked to a url. My site do not have that, I have instead a bunch of grid elements with news inside them and I want users to be able to comment and discuss the current grid element that the user clicked, maby add a popup window and the disqus in it
Is that possible?

Any kind of help or tips is appreciated.

Note: this is on a web application built with asp.net mvc 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Every thread does need a link - this is what we use to give users a link to comments from things like email notifications, or when aggregating content in other areas (e.g. Discovery).

If your site utilizes hashbangs (#!) in the URL, that's an acceptable URL to pass to Disqus. This documentation shows how to reload the Disqus thread without changing pages: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107